# Mikrotik: динамическое добавление IP адресов в список разрешенных при резолвинге DNS

Tags: сеть, безопасность, маршрутизация, роутер, mikrotik

В целях безопасности решил изолировать Windows Server от внешнего мира (правилами файрволла в роутере Mirkotik).

Но при этом хотелось бы иметь доступ к Windows Update. На [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b596aa81-2775-496c-b159-dcfc5c5bf22d/windows-update-ip-addresses-range-and-subnet-mask-for-windows-server-2008?forum=winserversecurity) говорят, что подсети постоянно меняются и советуют разрешить доступ к ресурсам, каждый раз их резолвя.

Вот их список:

- http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- http://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- https://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- http://*.update.microsoft.com
- https://*.update.microsoft.com
- http://*.windowsupdate.com
- http://download.windowsupdate.com
- http://download.microsoft.com
- http://*.download.windowsupdate.com
- http://wustat.windows.com
- http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com
- http://stats.microsoft.com
- https://stats.microsoft.com

Вопрос: как силами роутера разрешить к ним доступ?

Comment: "Резолвить" - это?

Comment: @edem разрешить доменное имя

Comment: Как я вижу решение: каким-то образом в скрипте (запускаемом раз в день) резолвить вышеперечисленные домены и добавлять их в Address List. А к IP в этом списке в правилах файрволла разрешить доступ. При этом, этим же скриптом нужно удалять все старые IP. 

Осталось лишь этот скрипт написать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если немного помучать базы данных radb.net, можно получить список адресов, закрепленных за Microsoft. Из него заполняем адрес листы:

```
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=65.52.0.0/15
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=65.54.0.0/20
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=65.55.0.0/16
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=103.81.184.0/22
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=131.107.0.0/16
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=157.54.0.0/15
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=157.56.0.0/14
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=157.60.0.0/16
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=167.220.0.0/16
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=198.105.232.0/22
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=198.180.95.0/24
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=199.2.137.0/24
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=199.242.48.0/22
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=204.182.144.0/24
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=204.255.244.0/23
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=205.248.126.0/23
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=206.138.168.0/21
```

IP4 свободных осталось не много, так что врятли они поменяются ближайшие годы. По этим спискам будут доступны все сервисы Microsoft на данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

Новые версии RouterOS поддерживают записи DNS в адрес листах:

```
/ip firewall address-list add list=microsoft address=windowsupdate.microsoft.com
```

Ресолвится всё автоматически.

Но пока не проверял работают ли звездочки (вроде нет).

Comment: Неа, не работают :(